# BAT script to copy files from Windows to remote Linux systems

Tags: windows, batch-file, winscp

Is there anyway to copy files from Windows machine to a remote Linux machine with a DOS command/other command-line tool (by specifying username and password in the command). I normally do this using WinSCP and would like to write a script (BAT) to automate this.

Comment: WinSCP can be run from scripts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the command line version of [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html), **[pscp.exe](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/x86/pscp.exe)**.

Comment: Technically pscp.exe isn't a command line version of PuTTY, only the secure-copy component.  plink.exe is the command line companion to PuTTY, though it is designed for remote commands without launching a shell.

Answer (score 6):

[WinSCP scripting command-line](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline#scripting) to upload a file is like:

```
winscp.com /command "open sftp://username@example.com/" "put d:\www\index.html" "exit"
```

See the [guide to WinSCP scripting](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation).

---

Easier is to use a [Generate transfer code function](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation#generating) to have WinSCP GUI generate a script (or even a complete batch file) for a transfer.

[image: Generate transfer code dialog]

Comment: Ty, for update about generate transfer function. This is actually where I planned to start at, and wasn't sure if it exists :)

Answer (score 5):

Download a copy of [pscp.exe](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) (the PuTTY scp companion).  If you have setup SSH keys on the Linux server, which you can do with PuTTY on Windows, you can setup password-less copy to Linux machines from Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Install cygwin and you can use scp, ssh etc just like you would on linux. Besides, you can use ordinary bash scripts instead of crappy bat-files.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is looking to do this in 2022, Windows 10 now comes with scp. You can do

scp path/localfile.txt remote-user@host:/home/path

or the recursive version for directories

scp -r localfolder remote-user@host:/home/path

Of course with scp you'll run into issues if you have a large number of files. It copies everything as opposed to only changed / new files only.

Then you'll need a tool like rsync, which is available through WSL (windows subsystem linux).

rsync -r localfolder remote-user@host:/home/path

(I personally hesitate to install new tools for a job, hence my desire to stick with what's already available)